# WebGL remove object from buffer

Tags: javascript, webgl

I add a new object to the webgl buffer with this code:

```
    triangleVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVertexPositionBuffer);
    var vertices = [
         0.0,  1.0,  0.0,
        -1.0, -1.0,  0.0,
         1.0, -1.0,  0.0
    ];
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

It works, but I don't know, how to remove this object from the buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glBufferData` does not put objects in a buffer. It allocates storage of the size you request and *copies* the data from the buffer you give it into the buffer object's internal data storage. So there's no "removing" of the object later; it's just copying it.

Comment: so if I don't need an object anymore, then I don't have to do anything with it?